# Loading multiple files from grails grails.config.location

Tags: grails

I am using grails 1.3.7. I have a `Config.groovy` file that specifies a number of other groovy file locations for the `grails.config.locations` property. I am unclear when these other files are parsed, so that I can use their information. At the time `Bootstrap.groovy` executes, for example, these files do not appear to have been parsed. Where is this stuff documented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This stuff is documented in the [Grails Configuration Documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#configExternalized)

In my experience, they should all be parsed by the time Bootstrap starts executing.

Comment: My bad -- I left the `grails` bit out of the config.